# Composing types In Typescript - Property does not exist on type

Tags: typescript

I'm new to typescript and I'm failing to understand type composition when using objects.

I have the following code :

```js
export interface Foo {
  birth: Date;
}

export interface Bar {
  death: Date
}

export type Baz = Foo | Bar
```

Why is it that, if I have a `Baz` typed object, I can't do the following

```js
const something = mybaz.birth; // Property birth does not exist on type Baz
```

How do I correctly solve this problem ?

My goal is to end up with something like this :

```js
const something = mybaz.birth ? mybaz.birth : mybaz.death;
```

Comment: The reason is simple  - `Baz` is not guaranteed to have that property. You've specified it's *either* `Foo` which has it *or* `Bar` which doesn't. You can do a type check to narrow down the available properties, if that's what you're after. Or perhaps you meant `Foo & Bar` to make a type that contains both properties.

Comment: `mybaz.birth ? mybaz.birth : mybaz.death` -> `"birth" in mybaz ? mybaz.birth : mybaz.death`. [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgMQgjgG8BYAKDjgCMFYALALjgBFNUBuSgX0stCRYiFGiy44AIUxRSlagBNgHZmw7Be-CoOjwYATzB5pALzgBeAkTgAfKTMpLsAGxl5sEJAGd4AW300mCYsptwUHt7wXhC+wDAMyADmFnAARHSMqSJw-oFmAPw5AUEAdBnxcCy5pUoqnEA) See: [type guards in the TypeScript handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-differentiating-types)